# Magento 2 in how to splited in bulk import child categories using(,)?

Tags: magento2.2, category-products

how to split in child categories in bulk import categories using (,)?

```
    Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Electrical Supplies,Default Category/Tools/Electrical Supplies/Boxes,Switches,Plugs & Sockets,Default Category/Tools/Electrical Supplies/Boxes,Switches,Plugs & Sockets/Electrical Boxes

bulk import in category is wrong path to created.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
products categoryes is separated and splited using to without space (,)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE9FN.png


Default Category/Too,Default Category/Too/Power Drilling_Fastening & Demolition Too,Default Category/Too/Power Drilling_Fastening & Demolition Too/Drill Bits_Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Too/Power Drilling_Fastening & Demolition Too/Drill Bits_Sets & Accessories/Masonry Drill Bits


its help..!
```